# Handling Arabic letters in QGIS and MapInfo

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, internationalization

I have a problem with QGIS and MapInfo, in both Windows XP and Windows 7.
I need to use French and Arabic.  One field is called Name_fr, and the other Name_AR.
The Arabic is fine until the moment I save the table, and all the characters turn into question marks.

Answer (score 7):

This issue came up with improvements to GDAL's handling of encoding. It was discussed [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/1-8-0-Broken-UTF-8-support-in-shapefiles-and-workaround-td4984666.html) on the qgis maillist. There are some suggested workarounds in that dicussion. I'm sure a permananet solution will appear soon, but what I found solves the problem fro now is the suggestion by Even Rouault:

First you need to have all the text attributes in your shapefile encoded as UTF-8. THen add to the batch file that starts QGIS (usually OSGEO4W\bin\qgis.bat) one line to set an enviroment variable:

```
SET SHAPE_ENCODING=UTF-8
```

With that, you can then save text strings (in my case in hebrew, but I suppose Arabic will be the same) without it getting turned into question marks.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac you can open a Terminal app and run:

$ SHAPE_ENCODING=UTF-8 /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS